# Autocomplete string of multiple words using 2 tries

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I'm currently using 1 trie for autocompletion. However, this only works if the string has the same starting character as the first character as the trie. ie, typing `santa` will display `santa clara` but when typing `clara` in the input box this result (`santa clara`) does not show.

How do I modify the code to use 2 tries - one for autocomplete a list of words and one for autocomplete for a list of characters? For example, if I were to type `clara` in the input box,  the results `santa clara` still displays?

```
//create node to be used to form a trie
class Node {
  constructor(value = '') {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
  }
}

//class Trie
class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.root = new Node();
  }

  add(value, parent = this.root) { 
    for (let i = 0, len = value.length; i < len; i++) {
      let node = parent.children.find(child => child.value[i].toLowerCase() === value[i].toLowerCase());
      if (!node) {
        node = new Node(value.slice(0, i + 1).toLowerCase()); //slice from 0 to i
        //console.log(node);
        parent.children.push(node);
      }
      parent = node;
    }
    return parent;
  }

  find(value, parent = this.root) {
    for (let i = 0, len = value.length; i < len; i++) {
      parent = parent.children.find(child => child.value[i].toLowerCase() === value[i].toLowerCase());
      if(!parent) return null;
    }
    return parent;
  }


  findWords(value, parent = this.root) {
    let top = this.find(value, parent);
    if (!top) return [];

    let words = [];

    top.children.forEach(function getWords(node) {
      if (!node.children.length) words.push(node);
      node.children.forEach(getWords);
    });

    return words;
  }

  createTrieFromArray(inputArr) {
    for (let item of inputArr) {
      let node = this.add(item);
      node.item = item;
    }
  }
}

const trie = new Trie(); 
const data = [
        "anaheim",
        "Agoura Hills",
        "Agua Dulce",
        "Aguanga",
        "Acalanes Ridge",
        "Acampo",
        "Acton",
        "Adelanto",
        "Adin",
        "san antonio",
        "san angelo",
        "san diego",
        "san jose",
        "san jacinto",
        "san francisco",
        "san bernardino",
        "san buenaventura",
        "san bruno",
        "san mateo",
        "san marcos",
        "san leandro",
        "san luis obispo",
        "san ramon",
        "san rafael",
        "san clemente",
        "san gabriel",
        "santa ana",
        "santa clarita",
        "santa clara",
        "santa cruz",
        "santa rosa",
        "santa maria",
        "santa monica",
        "santa barbara",
        "santa fe",
        "santee",
        "sandy",
        "sandy springs",
        "sanford"
      ];

trie.createTrieFromArray(data);
//console.log(trie);

const input = document.querySelector('input');
const results = document.querySelector('#results');

input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

  console.log(trie);
  let resultList=''; 
  const nodes = trie.findWords(e.target.value); // << Change
  console.log(e.target.value, 'nodes ', nodes);

  if (!nodes || !nodes.length) return; // << Change

  for (let node of nodes) { // << Change
    const category = node.category ? `- ${node.category}` : '';
    let oneResult =  `<li>${node.value} ${category}</li>`;
    console.log(oneResult);
    resultList += oneResult;
  }
  results.innerHTML = resultList;

});

input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  // Tab Key
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const current = trie.find(input.value);


    if (!current.children.length) return;

    input.value = current.children[0].value;
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you can split up words based on spaces, add them to trie with nodes having the list of actual string values.

Comment: this is not enough. it needs to maintain the order of the parent trie. For example, the 2 strings can be "apple banana" and "banana apple" and the user is typing "ana" both results should show up. First you need to check the chars within a word, and then compare the complete word against the string

Comment: So, just like `like %search%` of database. In this case, using a `trie` doesn't seem to  be the solution to me. Your best shot could be to iterate over them and check with `indexOf()` method to collect results.

Comment: Building on what @vivek_23 said, when you build the trie you could include fragments (words). For _apple banana_ and _banana apple_, you would insert _apple_ and _banana_, in addition to the whole strings themselves. The final node of each word (the letters _e_ and _a_ respectively) points to the list of original strings containing these words (both words point to both strings in these example).

Comment: @CătălinFrâncu yeah I think I'm trying to do what you're saying. I think I would need 2 tries: 1 trie to check against 1 word, the other trie is to check each word against the entire string.

Comment: @vivek_23 I think we're trying to say the same thing. I misunderstood you the first time.

Comment: @guest You said you need to match `banana` because it has `ana` and should show up in the results. Since `ana` is a part of `banana`, how will you percolate down the search in the trie? We aren't building a trie based on substrings too I presume.

Comment: it retains the order of both strings - 
Trie 2: `{root: {banana : {apple}, apple: {banana}}`
Trie 1: `{root: b: {a: {n: {a: {n :{a}}}}}, a: {p : {p: {l : {e}}}}}`
Once it finds the word in Trie 1, it has to do the same thing in trie 2. I'm having trouble connecting and modifying the code. Once it finds the word, it checks against trie 2 at every level to see if the word matches, it has to keep an array to count the words the whole time.

Comment: this is an interview problem so I know trie is the solution. I'm just practicing coding it

Comment: @guest Not sure how trie is really helpful here. If this is an interview question, how do you know solution uses trie? What if we have a string of size 10^5 in one of our dict words?

Comment: It doesn't matter what size, a trie is the most optimal solution. If larger than 10^5, you would have to split the string into sub-tries and connect them together at the end. this is a very popular algo problem and frequently asked interview whiteboarding question. https://youtu.be/J49el9Fl8lM - I saw this question here, that's why I tried to solve it - similar probs include url shortening, phone number look up, etc. they're in the same category of problems and optimally solved using a trie